# If I +1 a website (NOT a post) will my extended circle see it in their stream?

Tags: google-plus-1

If I +1 a website or an app (NOT a post in my stream or on someone else's profile), and my +1 setting is for extended circle, will they see this in their stream?  If I +1 the site by mistake and then remove the +1, will that be removed from their stream?  Google's help pages are not clear on this.